# Install arm librariers including dependencies on amd64

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, arm, architecture

i'm currently trying to install primarily libdbus-1.so (so the libdbus-1-dev:arm64 package) on my amd64 system so that I can cross compile a rust application. But it's not working somehow, because i'm always running in this error:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libdbus-1-dev:arm64
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libdbus-1-dev:arm64 : Depends: libdbus-1-3:arm64 (= 1.12.16-2ubuntu2.2) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Can anyone here tell me how I can install a arm64 package including it's dependencies on linux?

I'm running ubuntu 20.04 for your information.

Answer (score 0):

In a fresh minimal cross-compilation chroot I am able to install that package just fine

```
$ mk-sbuild --target arm64 focal
$ schroot -u root -c focal-amd64-arm64
(focal-amd64-arm64)# apt update; apt full-upgrade
(focal-amd64-arm64)# apt install libdbus-1-dev:arm64
...
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libdbus-1-3:arm64 libgcrypt20:arm64 libgpg-error0:arm64 liblz4-1:arm64
  liblzma5:arm64 libsystemd0:arm64
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libdbus-1-3:arm64 libdbus-1-dev:arm64 libgcrypt20:arm64 libgpg-error0:arm64
  liblz4-1:arm64 liblzma5:arm64 libsystemd0:arm64
0 upgraded, 7 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 1126 kB of archives.
After this operation, 3815 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
```

It might be the case that your local system has out of date packages installed for either host, or any other cross-compilation architecture preventing the installation. You might get better messages if you upgrade all packages, and list explicitly the package that apt complains about.

Please try:

```
$ sudo apt update; sudo apt full-upgrade
$ sudo apt install libdbus-1-3:arm64
$ sudo apt install libdbus-1-dev:arm64
$ sudo apt install libdbus-1-dev:arm64 libdbus-1-3:arm64
```

The above steps may produce different and hopefully more informative messages as to why apt is giving up on installing what you want.